# Moving React Native project to new folder

Tags: react-native

i need to move RN project to new folder, but when i do that. I get this error when i run the project using react-native run-ios. When running the project from original folder, there are no errors.

```
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening TestProject.xcworkspace

The following commands produced analyzer issues:
    Analyze /Users/home/Desktop/APLIKACE/TestProject/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi/jsi.cpp normal x86_64
    Analyze /Users/home/Desktop/APLIKACE/TestProject/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.cpp normal x86_64
(2 commands with analyzer issues)

The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/home/Desktop/APLIKACE/TestProject/ios/build/TestProject/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTUIUtils.o /Users/home/Desktop/APLIKACE/TestProject/node_modules/react-native/React/UIUtils/RCTUIUtils.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i figured out a solution, which is working for what i need to do ( move project to new empty folder where i initialized github repo ). 
 So it seems there are some issues with relative paths and names. So what i did was rename my old project like this

.../ParentFolder/MyProject to .../ParentFolder/MyProject2

i created new folder in ParentFolder with exactly same name as the original folder ie .../ParentFolder/MyProject. This was now empty folder i initialized as Git repo.

Then i copied contents of MyProject2 to MyProject folder. Everything is working now fine. 
Hope that helps someone in the future.